# Angularjs - falsy value filter

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var array = [{title:''},{title:'obj1'},{title:null,desc:'obj2'}];
```

I want to get only objects where `title` is not a falsy value (exists, not `null`, not empty string, etc).

So far I have this:

```
filterFilter(array,{title:'!'},true);
```

But I still get objects where `title` is `null`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var filtered = array.filter(function(item){
    return item.title;
})
```